# How do I populate a dropdown value on a webpage that will enable another dropdown for web automation via Javascript

Tags: javascript, power-automate-desktop

For RPA, I am trying to use Javascript to set a value in dropdown (A) which will enable dropdown(B). I can set the value of the dropdown (A), however it doesn't enable dropdown (B).

Is there something else I need to do, for it to recognize that I set the value in dropdown (A) and it should enable dropdown (B)?

Here is what I am using to set the value in dropdown (A):

```
function ExecuteScript()
{
document.querySelector('selector').value="value";
}
```

Comment: Do you already have a function to call to enable dropdown B? If you do, why don't you just call it at the point in code where you set the value of dropdown A?

Comment: @TKoL - Unfortunately I am just learning how to work with Javascript and don't know how to work with functions. Is there a site that you can point me to where I can learn more about working with Javascript for web automation?

Comment: is there a particular reason you are using javascript to set the value and not the automation? also the enabling of the second dropdown is most likely triggered by one of the events linked to dropdown A. `onChange()` or `onblur()` setting the value will not automatically trigger those events.